# Origine dell'espressione "Mi cade il mondo addosso"

Tags: phrase-origin

L'espressione

> Mi cade il mondo addosso

viene normalmente usata per indicare uno stato di difficoltà, misto a tristezza.

Vorrei sapere (non sono riuscito a trovare nulla in merito) qual è l'origine di tale frase.

Può essere collegata al mito di Atlante che nella mitologia greca era colui il quale teneva il mondo sulle sue spalle?

Comment: Anche in catalano diciamo "caure el món a sobre" o "caure el cel a sobre" (cioè, "cadere il cielo addosso").

Comment: @Charo: bene, quindi diventa davvero interessante scoprire questa etimologia!

Comment: Personalmente dubito che c'entri Atlante. Io semplicemente interpreto "il mondo" come "tutto" e quindi il detto nasce dal percepire un improvviso ed apparentemente insuperabile ostacolo come una completa distruzione di una situazione che si riteneva magari difficile, ma comunque gestibile.

Comment: In effetti io non sono d'accordo del tutto con la tua interpretazione: per farsi cadere il mondo addosso non è necessaria la tristezza (anche se è plausibile che ci sia) e non basta la difficoltà. Deve, a mio parere, verificarsi un evento (piuttosto puntuale) che trasforma una magari difficile in cui però c'è speranza (oppure è anche proprio priva di difficoltà) in una situazione completamente disperata. Se la situazione è difficile ma stazionaria secondo me non cade il mondo addosso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per quanto impossibile trovare on-line e sui vocabolari l'etimo esatto della locuzione, risulta in effetti chiaro il senso della frase. Il senso della locuzione

> **cadere** il mondo addosso (a qualcuno = qcn.)

anche spesso utilizzata nella forma

> **crollare** il mondo addosso (a qcn.)

è quello di un grave fatto, di una tragedia o comunque di un accadimento negativo generico che capita a qualcuno (*mi*, *ti*, *gli* ecc.).

Questo significato è quindi rappresentato in maniera *iperbolica* (cioè accentuata, esagerata) dal fatto che **qualcosa di molto grosso**, in questo caso il *mondo* - quindi ciò di grande, ma anche *mondo* inteso come ***tutto ciò che sta intorno a*** qcn. -, precipita *addosso*, e quindi si *"abbatte"* su qualcuno.

In effetti lo stesso significato simbolico di qualcosa che schiaccia qualcuno quando si parla di sfortune o accadimenti negativi si trova anche nell'uso di altre locuzioni come

> **abbattersi** su (qcn.)
>
> **imperversare** su (qcn.)

di cui un esempio potrebbe essere

> > 1. Una tragedia *si abbatté* sul povero sciagurato
> > 2. Le disgrazie *imperversavano* su Giorgio

## Breve epilogo

Dunque sebbene l'etimo esatto e la circostanza di nascita del termine non siano note, è ben evidente invece la figura che questa locuzione sta a rappresentare:

> un momento in cui tutto ciò che circonda il complemento di termine (colui cui *crolla il mondo addosso*), che subisce l'azione del soggetto *mondo*, viene meno, o, in ogni caso, un momento in cui accade un gravissimo fatto a qualcuno a cui reca un enorme dolore, ossia, in maniera figurata, un *peso*, da cui per estensione ciò che di più pesante si conosca: ***il mondo***.

Comment: Ciao, il significato mi era chiaro, ero curioso di conoscere proprio l'origine di questo termine

Comment: Trovo che questa lunga risposta aggiunga poco a quello che veniva già detto nella domanda.

Comment: @DaG: Penso che in realtà qualcosa venga aggiunto, e cioè il fatto che si usi anche dire «mi **crolla** il mondo addosso»; lo ritengo un utile indizio del fatto che sia assai improbabile che l’espressione abbia un’etimologia precisa (in particolare, che possa trarre origine dal mito di Atlante), e che sia piuttosto nata come *cliché*.  Per questi motivi, voto +1.